# IOS Swift read text file on server

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create ios application to read the content of text file on server but when I type this code I get the error: 
cannot call value of non-function type 'OperationQueue?' 
Replace with '()' with "

```
let url = URL(string:"http://www.1111.com/1.txt")!
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.currentQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
  if error != nil
  {
    println(error!)
  } 
  else
  {
    if let textFile = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
      println(textFile)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3 it's `current`. But you are mixing up Swift 2 and 3 code anyway.

Please use modern API

```
let url = URL(string:"http://www.1111.com/1.txt")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
       print(error!)
    } 
    else {
       if let textFile = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
          print(textFile)
       }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Please remember: NS = Not Swift

Comment: Thank you! It's working! How can I pass textFile value to other function?

Comment: Instead of the print line call the function.

Comment: I get error when I press button: fatal error: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
if let textFile = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                {
                    let url = URL(string: textFile)
                    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                }

Comment: Are you sure that the text is an URL without any additional characters?

Comment: Inside text file is ip address

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 solution -

```
func simpleAlertCheck() {
    var myURL = "http://www.yourURLhere.com/myTextFile.txt"
    do {
        var webString = try String(contentsOf: URL(string: myURL)!)
        print("Response: " + webString)
    } catch {
        print("There was an error")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
.onAppear(perform: {
                        simpleAlertCheck()
                    })
```

Note: You will also need to be sure to either use an HTTPS address or add the URL to the Exception list in your info.plist file or else you will get a error saying the app violated transport security

"App Transport Security Settings" > "Allow Arbitrary Loads" = YES

and

"App Transport Security Settings" > "Allow Arbitrary Loads"

Comment: This is not a better answer. You're recommending the usage of an API that will block the thread it's running on.