# import data from a txt file from a web

Tags: ios, json

I have the following structure and would like to import the data from a txt file but from a web page instead of the app, is there any way to do it?

I want to access the data through a web address.

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "archivotxt", ofType: "txt") {

        do {
            let contenido = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
            let fila = contenido.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            for i in 1..<fila.count {
                let datosArchivo = fila[i].components(separatedBy: "\t")
                //print(datosArchivo[1])
                let campos = Lista(nom: datosArchivo[0], dir: datosArchivo[1], tel: datosArchivo[2])
                self.lista.append(campos)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error al leer el archivo", error)
        }

    }else{
        print("no existe el archivo")
    }
```

Comment: You download the file first perhaps? Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I don't want to download the file, I want to access the data through a web address.

Comment: How could you possibly do that, to get the data you need to download it? Maybe this is just a confusion around terms, accessing a file via an Url and downloading it is the same thing for me. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861753/ios-swift-read-text-file-on-server) for a possible solution or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219848/how-to-download-file-in-swift)

Comment: I want the app to access some data from the web that is updated daily, but I do not want the file to be downloaded every time, I want to access the data of a .txt file that is in a web address

Comment: And did any of the links I gave you help?

Comment: I don`t use the links :(

Comment: Hard to help you then.

Comment: Apert from the issue you are encouraged to use a more reasonable text format like JSON or property list rather than simple tab separated lines. Then you can decode the data directly into your struct.

Comment: I found the solution, I wrote it down, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, I answer to myself, in case someone is interested

```
 let datos = "http://misitioweb/archivos/archivotxt.txt"


if let filePath = URL(string: datos) {
    do {
        let contenido = try String(contentsOf: filePath)
        let fila = contenido.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        for i in 1..<fila.count {
            let datosArchivo = fila[i].components(separatedBy: "\t")
            //print(datosArchivo[1])
            let campos = Lista(nom: datosArchivo[0], dir: datosArchivo[1], tel: datosArchivo[2])
            self.lista.append(campos)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error al leer el archivo", error)
    }

}else{
    print("no existe el archivo")
}
```